# Batch Compress and Watermark Images?

Tags: photo-editing, digital, image-compression, watermark

I am building a website for a client, and he needs some software to be able to add watermarks too, and slightly compress for bandwidth on his website. I'm struggling to find a solution that does both of these things.

Does anyone know of anything?

Comment: A normal workflow would be to shoot the images, upload to a catalog/edit program like Adobe Lightroom, and then use Lightroom’s function to export the images to web sizes (and watermark if needed as well). Thus, small, watermarked images are what’s being uploaded online. Why is your client deviating from this workflow? What’s their intended workflow?

Comment: Do you mean to watermark and compress images offline and then serve these images on the website? Or do you mean to watermark and compress images "on the fly" in the web server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about finding a solution to meet requirements in a web development problem, not about photography. This question is well-suited for [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this work with Batch Convert functionality of [XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/). As first step you select the images you want to manage, then filters/actions (resize, watermark), where to store the result and voila. Below is an image of program interface with resize and watermark plugins loaded:
[image]

NB! No affiliate with mentioned software.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical utility for batch image processing is ImageMagick. Its [`convert`](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command/component can change format, change compression parameters, and add text to a picture. It is free, open source, and can be used either as a command-line utility or as a library with binding for all major languages (Java, PHP, Python...).

Comment: I'm not saying that it is better (or worse), but there's also [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) which is a fork of IM and claims to be used by multiple picture hosting websites.